# PHP not checking if users exists and sending directly to profile page

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a login page but when I login it appears that the existence of the user/passwords it's not done, sending any input to the profile page.

I'm using PHP and MySQL. I've tried to redo the form, I checked all my code and it seems to be written do what I want.

I'm fairly new to PHP and MySQL, so I might be missing something.

This is the form code:

```
<form style="margin-top:40px;" action="includes/login.inc.php" method="post">
                <div class="form-group mb-3">
                <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                  <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-circle-08"></i></span>
                </div>
               <input class="form-control" id="name" name="username" placeholder="Utilizador" type="text">
             </div>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
             <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
             <div class="input-group-prepend">
               <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-lock-circle-open"></i></span>
             </div>
               <input class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password">
             </div>
             </div>
             <div class="custom-control custom-control-alternative custom-checkbox">
             <div class="text-center">
               <input class="btn btn-primary my-4" name="submit" type="submit" value=" Login ">
              </form>
```

And this is the login.inc.php code:

```
<?php

  include_once 'db.inc.php';

    session_start();
    $error = '';
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
        $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
      }
      else{

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query = "SELECT username, password FROM users where username=? AND password=? LIMIT 1";

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $username, $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->fetch())
          $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
        header("location: ../profile.php");
      }
      mysqli_close($conn);  
    }
?>
```

Anything I input, even if it's not on the `user` database, gets redirected to the `profile.php` page.

Comment: You don't actually check if the user exists. You just execute your query fetch anything, or nothing, and redirect.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use **[PHP's built-in functions](//php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the password_hash() **[compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)** (and you should consider upgrading to a supported version of PHP). Make sure you **[don't escape passwords](//stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so changes the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: What @JohnConde said! Saw you dropped by yesterday John, sorry to have missed you!

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'll swing by again so we can get caught up.

Comment: @JohnConde right now, I haven't created a register form. I added a user via phpMyAdmin just to test if I can get the login to work. I'll be looking at those hashing functions.

Comment: @JohnConde from what I've learned so far, I think this is what I wrote: 1. check if the form is empty, 2. ```$query``` checks if the form info matches the data on the database, 3.  if it matches, store the username in a session and then redirect the user to profile.php. As I said, I am new to PHP. Can you help with what am I missing out?

Comment: The problem is that you redirect in all circumstances. The `if($stmt->fetch())` statement is missing some brackets to allow more than one statement to be in it. Also you should always put die(); after issuing a redirect header, as this stops the rest of the page from being executed

Answer (score 1):

If all other code is fine you can try following replace of your if condition

```
if($stmt->fetch()){
  $_SESSION['login_user'] = $username;
  header("location: ../profile.php");
}
```